# copy a file to unix server from windows shared folder using unix command

Tags: java, python, scala, unix

copy a file to Unix server from windows shared folder using unix command

Example:- A shared drive on windows is- hostname\folderName and it contains a file name Test.txt inside it. Now I want to copy it on Unix server to process further.

How can I do it using Unix shell script or some coding concept of scala/java/python ?
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried upto now? Also why this question is tagged under bigdata/ apache-spark?

Comment: In actual requirement I need to copy files from windows shared folder to hadoop cluster but i didn't get any way to make it, so thought first try to copy file to edge node (unix server) local then will proceed further.

Comment: What file system you are using with hadoop cluster? HDFS/S3 etc etc??

Comment: Yes it is hdfs only.

Answer (score 1):

You could mount the shared drive and then copy the file to the server. Using commands in the Unix shell,

```
mount -t cifs //hostname/folderName /mnt/pathformount
cp /mnt/pathformount /pathforlocalcopy
```

Don't forget to unmount the drive when you are done.

```
umount /mnt/pathformount
```

Comment: I would like to know is there any option to copy a file from Hadoop edge node to windows shared drive path  ?  What  is the command do i  need to use for that

Answer (score 0):

You could try scp command, if you're using any shell on your windows try:

```
scp local/path your-name@ip.to.your.server:/path/to/send
```

Comment: I am facing below error while executing scp commandError: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host